# React: component subscribing to redux store changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently trying to use `react-redux` to subscribe to store changes for `newsItems` changes. My current component which is working but not listening for store changes as it should be looks like:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = { loading: false };
  displayName = Home.name

  render() {
    let contents = this.renderContents(store.getState().newsItems);

    return (
      <div>  
        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderContents = (newsItems) => {
    var largeNewsItems = newsItems.splice(0, 2);
    var firstNewsItem = largeNewsItems[0];
    var secondNewsItem = largeNewsItems[1];

    return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <LargeNewsItem newsItem={firstNewsItem} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <LargeNewsItem newsItem={secondNewsItem} />
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

when trying to update it to subscribe to teh store, I've made the following attempt:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = { loading: false };
  displayName = Home.name

  render(props) {
    let contents = this.renderContents(props.newsItems);

    return (
      <div>  
        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderContents = (newsItems) => {
    var largeNewsItems = newsItems.splice(0, 2);
    var firstNewsItem = largeNewsItems[0];
    var secondNewsItem = largeNewsItems[1];

    return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <LargeNewsItem newsItem={firstNewsItem} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <LargeNewsItem newsItem={secondNewsItem} />
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    newsItems: state.newsItems
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

which results in error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'newsItems' of undefined

where I call `props.newsItems`.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I overcome it?

UPDATE:
it looks like I can overcome it by using:
`render() {
    let contents = this.renderContents(this.props.newsItems);

```
return (
  <div>  
    {contents}
  </div>
);
```

}`

however my `LargeNewsItem` components will be passed null data once in a while. How can I overcome this and essentially "wait" until `newsItems` is populated

Comment: You are using a component class not a stateless component (function). In the stateless version you pass props as an argument but in your component, `props` is a field. Render should be `render()` and access `this.props` for the props.

Comment: Well, you likely forgot the `this` keyword for `this.props`. Render isn't called with any arguments. if you just want to render the existing props without local state, you could use a functional component instead. For your updated question, just check if `newsItems` is null or undefined, and only then render the content

Comment: Why you don't connect your component to redux store? With connect function react-redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to replace your render method as below .

`

```
render() {
const newsItems = this.props.newsItems;
if(!newsItems) {
return null;
}
    let contents = this.renderContents(this.props.newsItems);

    return (
      <div>  
        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }`
```

this way if your newsitems is null you wont get an error and once the newsitems uddates your render method will be called again